# Why can't string variable be used in <Image source={}/>? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

I am trying to do the following:

```
var itemImage = '../img/image1.jpg'

return(
        <Image
          source={require(itemImage)}
        />
```

but it keeps saying the error:

```
Requiring unknown module '../img/image1.jpg'.
```

But when I directly put in: '../img/image1.jpg' inside require() then it works.

What may be the issue? Any guidance or insight would be appreciated.

EDIT ***

I have the following in my constructor as my dataSource:

```
this.state = {dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([{name: '../img/item1.jpg'}, {name: '../img/item2.jpg'}])}
```

then in my renderRow(), I am trying to achieve something like the following so it updates based on the dataSource:

```
renderRow(rowData){
    var itemImage = require(rowData.name)

    return(
            <Image
              source={itemImage}
            />
```

But I am still getting the same error:

```
Requiring unknown module '../img/image1.jpg'.
```

Comment: Its not supported in react-native. Check this. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481#issuecomment-137982505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `require` with any *resource* file is a special case. It is not common javascript `require`. Packager must know what image will be required while **building** application (before any code executed) to replace it with *resource ID*. So parameter can't be variable and must be constant.

But you can simply do:

```
{
   dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
       {image: require('../img/item1.jpg')},
       {image: require('../img/item2.jpg')}
   ])
}
```

Comment: You the savior! Worked!

Answer (score 2):

Try this with single curly brace in image source.
and storing image path in image variable with require() method.

```
render(){
    var image=require('../img/image1.jpg');
    return(
       <View >
           <Image source={image}/>
       </View>
      );
 }
```

Comment: It works! But please check EDIT *** in the original post. I am trying to achieve that, but still getting an error.

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas Guni, it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797041/react-native-loop-through-object-array-using-an-array-to-create-components/56797211?noredirect=1#comment100150133_56797211